# Looking for buttons

Tags: button

I'm looking for similar buttons to [this](http://au.element14.com/schurter/12411104791/switch-spno-round-yellow/dp/150243) . A button where I can solder directly on the pcb. I plan to CNC mill out an acrylic bracket on top of this pcb, and was hoping i could just mill out a round hole, and have these buttons stick out for the user to press.

This button is a bit expensive, and it's got those plastic tabs, which I can't fit in my design (looking to get my whole setup as thin as I can, and those plastic tabs sticking out underneath the pcb isn't going to help :P)

Answer (score 1):

You can, in most cases, snap off the plastic tabs and then gently file off the stub if needed. The tabs are there for mechanical stability... maybe you can cut them to the required length?

How many do you need? Here's a handy "trick" if you only need a few, though this mostly works with ICs. Call up the distributor for the company in your area and ask for samples. Depending on the company, they'd be happy to send you some -- if you're a student this works even better.

Otherwise, try browsing through the distributors' online catalog for alternate parts; you may find alternatives you haven't yet considered. Or, search for "SWITCH, SPNO, ROUND".